# Map class property name in C#

Tags: c#

I am sending to Azure Mobile Service Custom API method some information - object of class AddFriendRequest.

```
public class AddFriendRequest
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to change property 'token' to 'MY-TOKEN'. What I should use to change that property name without changing class object name, something like:

```
public class AddFriendRequest
{
    ["MY-TOKEN"]
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the method of serialization you could use the data contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class AddFriendRequest
{
    [DataMember(Name="MY-TOKEN")]
    public string token { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string uuid { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure if it is wise to have a hyphon in the name of a property.